# Ruby faraday/em-http limit response body

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, faraday

I'm using faraday for external http calls.
But i need to limit (in kb's) response body size (or all response).

How i can do it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could limit it by using streaming, but currently there is no streaming support in Faraday

https://github.com/lostisland/faraday

> TODO:
>
> support streaming requests/responses